What are the advantages of using the Dirichlet kernel for interpolation?
Suppose we define the Dirichlet kernel as:
$$
\frac{\sin(\pi N x /2)}{N\sin(\pi x /2)}
$$
(Note: I'm not entirely sure what the standard definition of the Dirichlet kernel is; mine is slightly different than the Wikipedia one, for example. Comments on this are appreciated as well.)
I belive this can be shown to be an aliased version of a sinc function ($\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$). The Dirichlet kernel can be used as a lowpass interpolation filter, but as shown here, it has poorer frequency characteristics than a truncated windowed sinc.
My question is, in spite of its drawbacks, are there any advantages to using the Dirichlet kernel over a windowed sinc for band limited interpolation? For example, I've heard that it produces better results than a windowed sinc near the edges of a signal (where you get errors when the sinc filter runs over the edge of the data; thus it would be advantageous especially for short signals). I think this is related to treating the signal being interpolated as if it's been replicated (or mirrored) at the ends, but I can't find it worked out anywhere.

Is this question about using the advantages of Dirichlet vs. No interpolation or vs. some other interpolation?

@robertbristow-johnson the main alternative I have in mind is a windowed sinc filter for bandlimited interpolation, but there could be others. I've edited the question a bit.

I think that's better, Gillespie, because, especially if $N$ is large, you can have far fewer terms to add up.  I would suggest a Kaiser winder.  For perfect bandlimited interpolation, it's the Dirichlet thingie for odd $N$, but it's slightly different for even $N$.
